# How to put a custom view/layout pinned in CollapsingToolbarLayout ?

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

### Background

The support/design library allows to have a nice resize-as-you-scroll effect, using AppBarLayout and CollapsingToolbarLayout :

http://material-design.storage.googleapis.com/publish/material_v_3/material_ext_publish/0B0NGgBg38lWWcFhaV1hiSlB4aFU/patterns-scrollingtech-scrolling-070801_Flexible_Space_xhdpi_003.webm

### The problem

All examples I've seen are of Toolbar being the one pinned as you scroll.

What I'm trying to achieve is that a custom view will be pinned, in a size of a toolbar, while the content above it (some other views) will shrink as you scroll.

Something like that:

[image]

Thing is, no matter what I try, something doesn't work this way. Sometimes the content of the toolbar-replacement gets truncated, sometimes it doesn't get pinned, etc...

### What I've tried

Since for some reason the Toolbar is the only thing that seems to work well with the `app:layout_collapseMode="pin"` attribute, I tried to either put views in it, or put views with it.

Here's the current XML layout of what I've tried:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".ScrollingActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:padding="0px"
            app:contentScrim="#eeeeee"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
                app:title="">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0px"
                android:background="#33ff0000"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="#33ffff00"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="someText"
                    android:textColor="#000"/>

            </LinearLayout>


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_scrolling"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Sadly, even though the layout editor shows that it looks ok, what I actually see is this truncated text for the toolbar-replacement view:

[image]

I also tried using `layout_anchor`, as shown on a sample of how to use it ([**here**](https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorBehaviorExample)), but even then, the view that is supposed to replace the toolbar seems to overlap the content that's supposed to be below it and the one above it, and even the view that's above it have some space below it that isn't supposed to be there:

[image]

And here's the XML layout of this try:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#3300ff00"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="none">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:text="need to be right above 'someText'"
                    android:textColor="#ff000000"/>

            </FrameLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lorem"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#33ff0000"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/title"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:title="">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="someText"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

### The questions

How can I put custom views so that the toolbar content will stay between the bottom and upper areas, not overlapping any of them, and have the area above the toolbar to shrink as you scroll ?

Answer (score 0):

For now, I'm using a workaround for this issue, by using padding that will prevent the overlapping of the views. I still don't get why the views overlap, but this helps against it.

The problem with this, is that now the toolbar doesn't have a shadow when I scroll enough so that it's the only thing that appears at the top.

Here's a sample XML layout, in case anyone wants to try:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#3300ff00"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingBottom="24dp"
                app:layout_collapseMode="none">

                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:background="#f00"/>

            </FrameLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="24dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="0dp"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lorem"/>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:background="#33ff0000"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/title"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
        app:title="">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="someText"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```